# how to change hierarchy on prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and working on a image viewer in unity2D.

I am not sure if I choose components true but for now working fine.
most of the project is script based
I created a prefab which has a raw image 
and in script I Instantiate prefabs in a scrollviews content 
images are displayed no problem in that 
I added some events where I Instantiate my prefab pointerDown, beginDrag, endDrag
dragging workin fine too
but when I drag any added prefab to older added prefab it stays on top but if I drag it to a newer added prefabs it stays under them. 
I think its because the hierarchy order.
how can I change the order or how can I manage to make prefab stay on top when dragging
ps: on the image thumb_0 is added first and after drag it stays on behind thumb_2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can access the Transform of your prefabs you can use the method SetAsLastSibling(); it will move your gameobject to the last spot under your parent object, therefore causing it to be drawn on top
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html

EDIT :unless you mean dragging it manually, so then drag it to the bottom , last item always appears on top

Comment: I would clarify that the objects are rendered down the hierarchy. Highest gets rendered first which means it will appear behind a lower object rendered on top of it. :)

Comment: I want dragging object to be seen. setting SetAsLastSibling() is great for me thanks